# Refused to display 'https://stackblitz.com/edit/zknwqv.run' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: angular, google-chrome, iframe, stackblitz

I embedded a new project using the stackblitz API. When I click the .run button (Following Screenshot). It went unresponsive. The console says "Refused to display 'https://stackblitz.com/edit/zknwqv.run' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

**If they doesn't allow to display on iframe. Why should they put a API. Or Am I missing anything**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with Stackblitz. Issue created at github.